# Explanation of Lookup function with minus sign in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

While searching for solutions to extract numbers from alphanumeric strings, I stumbled across following formula in [MrExcel](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/463005-extract-number-alphanumeric-string.html) forum. I am having a hard time understanding what the minus symbol is doing in front of `LOOKUP` and `RIGHT` function in the formula. The formula is given as

```
=-LOOKUP(1,-RIGHT(TRIM(LEFT(D1,FIND("g/L",D1)-1)),{1,2,3,4,5,6}))
```

Can somebody explain to me what the formula does and why there are minus symbols in it?

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

Short answer is that the minus signs do a multiply by -1

- first over items in the array returned by the `RIGHT` function to deliberately generate `#VALUE!` errors in the array (because strings cannot be multiplied), and
- second to reverse the fact that the candidate answers from the `LOOKUP` formula - numbers-as-strings in the array - are now negative but need to be positive once the entire formula has evaluated.

### Original question on MrExcel

OP on that forum asks:

> Looking for assistance in figuring out the best formula to extract the VOC content value from variable length alphanumeric string. The VOC content is the number just before the "g/L".

And a data sample is:

`SEALANT-RETAINING COMPOUND SINGLE COMPONENT ANAEROBIC, SCR40372A, *Loctite 242, 10 ML BOTTLE,146 g/L VOC`

`SEALANT-THREAD LOCK *HIGH STR *MIL-S-22473 *GRADE AA *50 ML BOTTLE * * *SCR802269A\ * Loctite 089 Weld Sealant125.3 g/L VOC`

Where the answer they want is `146` or `125.3`.

In the thread, an answerer (pgc01) posts this formula:

`=-LOOKUP(1,-RIGHT(TRIM(LEFT(D1,FIND("g/L",D1)-1)),{1,2,3,4,5,6}))`

(where D1 would contain that string)

### Simplified example

The original thread is looking to extract a numeric value of unknown length from a string of unknown length where the placeholder is `g/L`. Put that to one side and let us simply consider the following strings:

`foobar123`

`foobar1234`

`foobar12345`

Where the challenge is get the numeric part without knowing how long it is (where the number won't exceed 6 digits). You can't just use `RIGHT` normally as you don't know how many characters to put in the 2nd argument. We are not using VBA so we need a way of iterating over the text and figuring out what are numeric and non-numeric strings so we can just pull out the numeric portion.

### Analysis of formula

So now the formula you are looking at is just:

`=-LOOKUP(1,-RIGHT("foobar123",{1,2,3,4,5,6}))`

Breaking the formula down:

- `RIGHT("foobar123",{1,2,3,4,5,6})` - in the context of the whole formula this is returning an array of results `3`, `23`, `123`, `r123`, `ar123`, `bar123`. You can't directly see this in Excel normally but you can if you use the Insert Function wizard to inspect the `LOOKUP` formula.

[image]

- Adding the minus sign at the front of the `RIGHT` function has the effect of multiplying each item of the array by -1 which now gives us an array of `-3`, `-23`, `-123`, `#VALUE!`, `#VALUE!`, `#VALUE!`. The error values are intended because we can now infer that the numeric portion of the string is 3 digits because any further right is giving errors i.e. you can not multiply an alphabet character by -1 and get a meaningful result.

[image]

- Next use the `LOOKUP` function to find 1 in this array i.e. `=LOOKUP(1, etc)`. All our numeric results in the array are negative so all the results will be less than 1. The `LOOKUP` function will return the largest value in the array that is less than or equal to the lookup value (see below) which in our case will be the result that has the most digits and is therefore the correct 'capture' as we are searching for the numeric portion of the string from the right-hand side. Its implied the behavior just skips the `#VALUE!` errors. So, in our example this will return `-123`.

[From MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192952.aspx)

> Array form
>
> The array form of LOOKUP looks in the first row or column of an array for the specified value and returns a value from the same position in the last row or column of the array. Use this form of LOOKUP when the values that you want to match are in the first row or column of the array. Use the other form of LOOKUP when you want to specify the location of the column or row.
>
> Tip In general, it's best to use the HLOOKUP or VLOOKUP function instead of the array form of LOOKUP. This form of LOOKUP is provided for compatibility with other spreadsheet programs.
>
> **If LOOKUP can't find the lookup_value, it uses the largest value in the array that is less than or equal to lookup_value.**
>
> If lookup_value is smaller than the smallest value in the first row or column (depending on the array dimensions), LOOKUP returns the #N/A error value.

- Finally the minus operator before the `LOOKUP` function multiplies the evaluated result by -1 giving us `123`.

### Tests

`=-LOOKUP(1,-RIGHT("foobar123",{1,2,3,4,5,6}))` gives `123`

`=-LOOKUP(1,-RIGHT("foobar12345",{1,2,3,4,5,6}))` gives `12345`

`=-LOOKUP(1,-RIGHT("foobar123456789",{1,2,3,4,5,6}))` gives `456789` (because the array in the 2nd argument of the `RIGHT` function only goes up to 6.

`=-LOOKUP(1,-RIGHT("foobar123baz",{1,2,3,4,5,6}))` gives `#N/A` because of the `baz` bit.

So in the original thread on MrExcel there use looking for the `g/L` item in the string and taking the left hand side of that as a way to ensure that some unknown number (up to 6) of right-hand-most characters will be numeric.

### Conclusion

Some people might want to get out VBA and regex tools at this point but for people who want, or need, to do everything with formulas this provides a method of doing a sort of fuzzy-match to identify important information in text data.

Comment: Superb, well done, thanks for the detail which will help me as well.